# I want to traverse the links of a page, but my program gets terminated in between without throwing any error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class CountingBrokenLinks {
    static int count = 0;
    static int currentElement = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.hindustantimes.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("amenu-india-col")));
        List<WebElement> listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        int noOfLinks = listOfLinks.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfLinks; i++) {
            WebElement element = listOfLinks.get(currentElement);
            if (!(element.getText().isEmpty())) {
                String linkText = element.getText();
                System.out.println(linkText);
                driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).click();
                String title = driver.getTitle();
                if (title.contains("error")) {
                    count++;
                }
                driver.navigate().back();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("amenu-india-col")));
                listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                currentElement++;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I want to visit http://www.hindustantimes.com/ and traverse all the links in the page. If any of the page title contains the word "Error" I want to increment the count.

Previously I was getting `StaleElement` Exception, but I initialized the list again and to maintain the index I'm using static variable.

The program gets terminated at this line:-

```
String linkText = element.getText();
```

Because its not displaying the text (Using this for debugging purpose) I don't understand why the program is terminated.

Comment: You pass currentElement=0 then how it works dear pass i instead of currentElement

Answer (score 1):

Your program looks fine, but you should change the following line of code:

```
WebElement element = listOfLinks.get(currentElement);
```

to

```
WebElement element = listOfLinks.get(i);
```

because you set the `currentElement` value to `0`, so your code will not traverse through all the elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the `<a>` tags, including the first one, don't have text which means

```
if (!(element.getText().isEmpty()))
```

Is `false` in the first round so `currentElement` is never incremented and you keep getting the first `<a>` tag in the line

```
WebElement element = listOfLinks.get(currentElement);
```

Instead of using variable just use the `i` index from the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfLinks; i++) {
    WebElement element = listOfLinks.get(i);
    //...
}
```

You program doesn't terminate on the `element.getText();`, it runs until the loop condition is not longer valid.

Comment: Ohh okay got your point. I was a bit confused with the re-initialization of list and some how created a new static counter instead of using i. I will try this out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `i` instead of the `currentElement`, your code is like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfLinks; i++) {
        WebElement element = listOfLinks.get(i);
        if (!(element.getText().isEmpty())) {
            String linkText = element.getText();
            System.out.println(linkText);
            driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).click();
            String title = driver.getTitle();
            if (title.contains("error")) {
                count++;
            }
            driver.navigate().back();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("amenu-india-col")));
            listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            currentElement++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Iterator interface to iterate among the elements instead of using `if` loop. Let me know if it works.

```js
List<WebElement> listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
Iterator <WebElement> it = listOfLinks.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            WebElement element = it.next();
            if (!(element.getText().isEmpty())) {
                String linkText = element.getText();
                System.out.println(linkText);
                driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).click();
                String title = driver.getTitle();
                if (title.contains("error")) {
                    count++;
                }
                driver.navigate().back();
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("amenu-india-col")));
                listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                currentElement++;
```